# How to update text in a loop?

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm basically a beginner in C++ but was looking into how to update a string that is in a while loop?

Currently every iteration of the loop it writes the text on top of the previous still its basically a blur of white colour.

This is my loop that im testing with:

```
while(!quit){
    while( SDL_PollEvent( &event ) ){
        switch(event.type){
            case SDL_QUIT: quit = true; break;
            case SDL_MOUSEMOTION: handle_mouse_position();
        }
    }

    SDL_Rect offset;
    offset.x = 400;
    offset.y = 290;

    std::stringstream s;
    s << "Mouse xpos: " << mouseX << " Mouse ypos: " << mouseY;

    font_surface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font,s.str().c_str(),font_color);
    SDL_BlitSurface(font_surface, NULL, screen, &offset);   

    //Update the screen
    if( SDL_Flip( screen ) == -1 ) {
        return 1;    
    }
}
```

Is there some way to clear the previous text output and update it each loop so that it will display mouse position clearly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that redrawing everything each time, or if your background is a solid color, paint a rectangle and draw the text above it.

The second one is more efficient. But if you have a complex scenario it is better to work with layers. First you render the bottom layer, then the second, and so on... By layers I mean, you can have a `background()` which draws the background and `foreground()` which, obviously, draws the foreground. So what you will have is something like:

```
while (main_loop) {
    background();
    foreground();
}
```

So you can easily handle more complex scenarios.

Comment: Which is more efficient and how would i do the syntax for it ?

Comment: The second one is more efficient. But if you have a complex scenario it is better to work with layers. First you render the bottom layer, then the second, and so on...

Comment: I tried this: `font_color SDL_MapRGB(SDL_PixelFormat, 92,132,205);
SDL_FillRect(font_surface,&offset,font_color);` but it's not happy =/

Comment: Did you forget to `SDL_BlitSurface()`?

Answer (score 1):

You are not clearing the screen between redraws, so it just paints over the already painted text (or anything), and it becomes "blur of white" as you say.

For example, try fillrect on the screen every frame.

Extra note: it seems you are not freeing the font_surface --> memory leak.

Comment: whats the correct syntax for it i can't seem to work it out =/

Comment: its the colour i can't work out =/ the format for a specific colour i want.

Comment: To find the color: __font_color = SDL_MapRGB( screen->format, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00 );__